# How do I make rapidly changing text in chat and signs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I make rapidly changing text in chat and signs?

I have seen this done in adventure maps. I wanted to use this in my own map but I don't know how.

Comment: What you're looking for is either §k or &k, but I am pretty sure that you can't do it on SinglePlayer unless you use something like NBEdit. 

A lot of servers have it to where you can, but you first need to make sure you have access to it. If you use &k and nothing happens, then you don't have access to it. If you get a bunch of jumbled up characters, then you know you do.

Answer (score 5):

This is using the "obfuscated" JSON option. It does not require a server or external program as LucidiousXIV said, it **does** however require access to commands, which I assume you already have if you're making an adventure map.

To `/tellraw` it into chat:

```
/tellraw @a {"obfuscated":"true","text":"This text will not be seen"}
```

To make a sign with it:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ standing_sign 0 replace {Text1:"{\"text\":\"This text will not be seen\",obfuscated:\"true\"}"}
```

Comment: If you want the sign to face another direction, just change the number after 'standing_sign' to 0-7.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this,(this works for me even without access to commands) you have to have a sign and write §k. Then you can type anything. (Do note if you go to the next line, even though it looks like it is still scramble while you write it, it’s not. The way to fix this is to write §k again or write §r.

Comment: in the most recent versions of minecraft, you cannot input a silicent(§) anywhere in minecraft. This includes signs, commandblocks, and chat. Using JSON arrays is the only way to change color and format.